# Why does Rust return a different address for a vector and its first element?

Tags: rust

I am trying to print the address of a vector.

```
fn main() {
    let g = vec![1,2,3];
    println!("great {:p}, {:p}", &g, &g[0])
}
```

This prints `great 0x7fff379f9e90, 0x564dc99e29d0`

I am wondering why the addresses are different. To the best of my knowledge, I can't directly print `g` as we could do in C++. So I did `&g`. That should still give the address of the vector (the starting point) which is the same thing as `&g[0]`.

Why are they different?

Comment: A vec is not an array, it is a datastructure. If you know C++. would you expect a `std::vector` to have the same address as its first value?

Comment: Vec lives on the stack, its data on the heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are they different ?

Because they are different. `&g` is the address of the vector struct on the stack.

Much like `std::vector`, a Rust `Vec` is a triple of `{buffer*, size, capacity}`. `&g` gets you an address to that structure, not the address of the vec's internal buffer (which is accessible through `&*g`, or `g.as_slice()`, or `g.as_ptr()`).

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, when you print `&g` you are printing the address in the *stack* of the structure definition of `Vec`

**Documentation:**

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html